# Play Audio when Joining a Voice Channel DiscordJS v13

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've been trying all night to get a simple task working, but yet I am not able to figure out how.
Basically what I achieved is that the Bot joins a Voice Channel when somebody joins, play an Audio file and that's it. What I want to achieve is that it joins when somebody joins, play the Audio file and then leave and as when somebody leaves the voice chat. It's supposed to join the voice chat, play a different audio file and then leave again.
All in all seems easy, but I've been banging my head against it with no results. If possible I would also like to have the code be tidy there aswell.
Here is the code (using discord.js v13):

```
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
    
    if (oldState.channelId === null) {
        console.log("Joined")
        //playAudio(newState.channelId, './files/bruh.mp3')
        const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
            channelId: newState.channelId,
            guildId: newState.guild.id,
            adapterCreator: newState.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
          })
          console.log(newState.guild.voiceAdapterCreator)
          const player = createAudioPlayer();
          connection.subscribe(player)
          
          const resource = createAudioResource('./files/riff.mp3')
          player.play(resource)
          
          
    } else if (newState.channelId === null) {
        console.log("Left")
    }
    
});
```

Edith: With when somebody joins. I mean when somebody joins Voice Chat.

Comment: If you saying that if someone joined the server or leave the server, the bot will join a vc? Isnt the join and leave server should be the `guildMembersAdd` and `guildMembersRemove`?

Comment: With Join, I mean when somebody joins a Voice Chat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a Good Nights sleep I was able to figure it out, for anyone corious, here is the code!

```
var isReady = true

function playAudio(chID, guID, adpID, audioFile) {
    isReady = false
    const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
            channelId: chID,
            guildId: guID,
            adapterCreator: adpID,
        })
          
          const player = createAudioPlayer();
          connection.subscribe(player)
          
          const resource = createAudioResource(audioFile)
          player.play(resource)
          player.on(AudioPlayerStatus.Idle, () => {
            connection.destroy()
        });
          
        isReady = true
}
```